# How can I select limiting the count of a column dataframe? PYTHON

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe called houses. One column is houseID and I want to get the information of only 1000 diferent houses. There are more than 1 row with the same houseID (houses with more or less number of rows). For that I cannot get only the 1000 first rows, I need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM houses WHERE COUNT(DISTINCT houseID) <= 1000
```

Reduced example (original dataframe with 3 different houseID, I want 2 different houseID in this reduced example):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd
housesDict = OrderedDict([ ('houseID', ['1', '3', '1','2','2','1','3','1','1']),
                ('Cost', [150, 200, 50,100,75,18,10,23,19])])
houses = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(housesDict)
print(houses)
```

If I want to limit the different number of houses to 2, my expected output is:

```
housesDict = OrderedDict([ ('houseID', ['1', '3', '1','1','3','1','1']),
                    ('Cost', [150, 200, 50,18,10,23,19])])
houses = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sales)
print(houses)
```

How can I do it?

EDIT:
I have the solution, thanks for the help:

```
a = list(df.drop_duplicates(subset=["houseID"]).iloc[:2]['houseID'])
df[df['houseID'].isin(a)]
```

Comment: Your desired result does not match your problem description, for instance why is 2 excluded when it also has 2 distinct sales the same as 3? besides are you after `df.groupby('houseID').filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 2)`?

Comment: @EdChum I want all the rows of 1000 differents houseID. In total, in my table I need 1000 different houseID and I want to have all the rows in the original dataframe of these 1000 differents houseID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the distinct values, you can simply use [drop_duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["houseID"]).iloc[:1000]
```

If you want to limit the number of repetitions, you can use [groupby.transform('count')](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with boolean indexing.

```
df.loc[df.groupby("houseID")["houseID"].transform('count') < 3].iloc[:1000]
```

---

EDIT: misunderstood the question, you can use the functions above to index values.

```
# gets first 1000 unique id's
unique_ids = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["houseID"]).iloc[:1000]["houseID"]
# selects rows if their ID's are in unique_id dataframe
df = df.loc[df["houseID"].isin(unique_ids)]
```

Comment: I want all the rows of 1000 different houseID. In my example I have 3 different houseID and I want only 2 different houseID (is an example, in my original dataset I have more than 1 M of different houseID and I want all the rows of 1000 different houseID)

Comment: @zorro did you try `drop_duplicates` it will give you 1000 rows (if exists) of different houseID's and their rows (first seen).

Comment: I want something like `SELECT * FROM houses WHERE COUNT(DISTINCT houseID) <= 1000`, being houses the dataframe and houseID the column :S

Comment: Yes, but I want the duplicates, I dont want to drop them. I want 1000 different houses but each row gives me different information

Comment: Ah got you now, you can use filter or index by the values you got, let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thank for the help mate ;)